# Trouble sending email on behalf of another person in a cakephp 2.0 application

Tags: cakephp

I have a form where users enter their email and the email of a friend. If the email validates, my controller uses the email class to send a message to the friend. I would like to have the friend receive an email that was "from" the user but can not get it work. I can only get emails to send successfully if I set the sender to something static, like "myname@mydomain.com" Here's my form:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array( 'action' => 'invite',
                                    'controller' => 'users')  
                                    );
    echo $this->Form->input('User.from', array('label'=>"Your email",'value'=>'your email','class'=>"",'type'=>'email'));
    echo $this->Form->input('User.to', array('label'=>"Your friend's", 'value'=>"your friend's email",'class'=>"",'type'=>'email'));
    echo $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'Invite', 'class'=>'special-button use-transition')); 
?>
```

My Users controller then handles the form. This works successfully in that I can get the app to send email messages to valid email addresses. However, if I try to set $from to the user's email address, it doesn't send anything. How can I send this email *from* the email address entered by a user? Here are the pertinent sections of user controller:

```
// tell app to use Cake Email
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email'); 

public function invite(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Get data from the form and send an email
        $to = $this->request->data['User']['to'];
        $from = $this->request->data['User']['from'];
        $subject = "Some text for the subject line";
        $message = "Some text for the message";
        // I use this data to send an email but it won't work unless
        // I change $from to something static like so:
        $from = "myemail@mydomain.com";
        $this->send($to, $from, $subject, $message);
        // redirect on success not shown...
    }
}

// Send function takes the to/from/subject/message and sends it
public function send($to, $from, $subject, $msg) {
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->template('welcome')
          ->emailFormat('html')
          ->from($from)
          ->to($to)
          ->subject($subject);
    if ($email->send($msg)){
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to Collect the Sender's Name too and add to the from Field.

So your form should be like:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array( 'action' => 'invite',
                                'controller' => 'users')  
                                );
 echo $this->Form->input('User.fromName', array('label'=>"Your Name", 'value'=>"your name",'class'=>""));
echo $this->Form->input('User.from', array('label'=>"Your email",'value'=>'your email','class'=>"",'type'=>'email'));
echo $this->Form->input('User.to', array('label'=>"Your friend's", 'value'=>"your friend's email",'class'=>"",'type'=>'email'));
echo $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'Invite', 'class'=>'special-button use-transition')); 
?>
```

And in your invite function let the $formMail be like this:

```
 $fromMail = array($this->request->data['User']['from'] => $this->request->data['User']['fromName']);
```

Hope this gets it work

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later today

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't really work. Rather, I can only get it to work if I don't put the requested data in as an email. Thus, this works: $fromMail = array("myname@myapp.com" => $this->request->data['User']['fromName']); But of course this doesn't really meet my need because the email still appears to come from my app. You might wonder if I am actually getting the email using data['User']['from'] but I am. I tried debugging it and it gives me a string like "myname@domain.com"

Comment: Well :) I  just gave it a try here and submitted the E-Mail as a variable and not a hard-coded string like your example here and It worked perfectly. I even tried it without submitting a Name & it worked too: 
$email->from($this->request->data['User']['from_email']);

Try to trim the value of the $from variable ...->from(trim($from));

I don't see anything wrong with your code up there. Should work the way you posted it already without my proposed changes.